# For multiplication with conditional probabilities, why can't $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n = \emptyset$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

My book says this for the formula of multiplication with conditional probabilities:

For any events $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$ with $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n \neq \emptyset$

$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n) = P(A_1)P(A_2 |A_1)P(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)...P(A_n|A_1\cap A_2  \cap ...\cap A_{n-1})$

This makes intitutive sense to me as $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n)$ is just equivalent to $P(A_1)$ occurs and then given that $A_1$ occurs, we need $A_2$ to occur too, and then,
given that $A_1$ and $A_2$ occur, we need $A_3$ to occur too, and then,
given that $A_1$ and $A_2$ and $A_3$ occur, we need $A_4$ to occur too and so on till we reach $P(A_n|A_1\cap A_2  \cap ...\cap A_{n-1})$ and stop because then all the events in the intersection in the LHS occurred!

My question is, why isn't $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n \neq \emptyset$ allowed? Wouldn't that just make $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n) = 0$ which is a completely legimately value for probability? Is any mathematical law broken with $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n = \emptyset$ that makes it not allowed?

Thank You!

Comment: That is a strange statement. The equation is valid as long as all the conditional probabilrites are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right condition you want is $P(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{n-1}) \neq 0$, however, this is not implied by $A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{n-1} \neq \emptyset$ (unless maybe your book considers discrete probability spaces and requires no $0$-sets).

If $A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{n-1} = \emptyset$ (or even $P(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{n-1}) = 0$), then the last probability would not be defined since

$$P(A\vert B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

However, if $P(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{n}) = \emptyset$ and $P(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{n-1}) \neq 0$ then the formula is well defined and true since the LHS is $0$ and the last enumerator in the last factor is also $0$.

Comment: Non-empty does not mean non-zero probability.

Comment: Yes, of course. I should have been more careful

Comment: I am not going to edit my answer I already downvoted yours for being incomplete, now we are even :)

Answer (score 0):

Every probability measure verifies that $P(\emptyset)=0$

So $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n = \emptyset$ $\implies$ $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n) = P(\emptyset)=0$ is trivial

The most important property that probability measures have (that other measures doesn't necesarily verify) is that if two events A, B are independent then $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$

Comment: Why the down vote? They just put the property $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n = \emptyset$ because then $P(\emptyset)=0$ and is trivial.

Comment: Is just common to see it when you read it in any books about probability.

Comment: I downvoted because I do not see how that answers the question

Comment: Someone already pointed to you that non-empty set does not mean non-zero probability. Besides you can have $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n = \emptyset$ with $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_{n-1} \neq \emptyset$. So you don't  give an answer to why $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n$ must be $\emptyset$, indeed it doesn't need to verify. The only reason it's there is because is $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n = \emptyset$ then the problem is trivial.

Comment: Again, I don’t see how you answer the question. The first and second point of your answer are already implicitly stated by OP, and the last has nothing to do with the question. The question is about why a certain condition makes sense to require, and I don’t see this being addressed

Comment: Yes, absolutely I adressed it, I said it's basically pointless, The condition is just used to disregard the obvious case. And did you adress it? Again, no.

Comment: If you say you addressed the question in your answer I genuinely do not see where and how. But if you would edit to give a more explicit answer (maybe explain why "it's basically pointless") I am more than happy to remove the downvote or even give an upvote.

Comment: $$P(A_n | A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{n-1}) = P(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{n})/P(A_n) $$
if $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n = \emptyset$ then $\rightarrow$
$$P(A_n | A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{n-1}) = P(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{n})/P(A_n)=0$$
so the result is trivial and the formula is trivially verified.